# Error trying to save a record with server created in react, graphql and apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, mutation

When i try to send a register from my UI to mi SERVER, that send me this message

> POST http://localhost:4000/graphql 400 (Bad Request) index.js:70
>   [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$description" of required type
>   "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path:
>   undefined index.js:75 [Network error]: ServerError: Response not
>   successful: Received status code

This is my class component

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Query, Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import BrandItem from '../models/BrandItem';
import * as BrandService from '../services/BrandService';

export class Brand extends Component {
  render() {
    let input;

    return (
      <div className="divform">
        <Mutation mutation={BrandService.ADD_BRAND}>
          {
            (addBrand, { data }) => (
              <form onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addBrand({ variables: { type: input.value } });
                input.value = '';
              }}>
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="description" name="description" required ref={node => { input = node; }} />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
              </form>
            )
          }

        </Mutation>
        <div>
          <Fragment>

            <Query query={BrandService.BRAND_QUERY}>
              {
                ({ loading, error, data }) => {
                  if (loading) return <div><h4>loading....</h4></div>
                  if (error) console.log(error);

                  return <Fragment>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {
                          data.brands.map(brand => (
                            <BrandItem key={brand.id} brand={brand} />
                          ))
                        }
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </Fragment>
                }
              }
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brand
```

And this is my service

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const BRAND_QUERY = gql`
  query BrandQuery {
    brands {
      id
      description
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_BRAND = gql`
  mutation AddBrand($description: String!){
    addBrand(description: $description){
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the issue is in this line.

```
addBrand({ variables: { type: input.value } });
```

Here you are passing the variable type where as the mutation needs description. Therefore changing to the following should solve your issue.

```
addBrand({ variables: { description: input.value } });
```

Good luck and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hello Sean, thank you very much for your help, it was really that. I'm starting with these topics, could you tell me what structure or how to design my application? Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to have helped. You look like you are doing pretty well already. For me personally I would seperate out the views from the data fetching. So your form would be a seperate component and you could pass down the addBrand prop.